# Can you say what type of algebraic structure this is?

Tags: lie-algebras

What type of algebraic structure is given by the following?
\begin{align}
[X, Y] &= iH,\\
[H, X] &= -i\{H, Y\},\\
[H, Y] &= i\{H, X\},
\end{align}
where $[ \cdot,\cdot ]$ is a commutator and $\{ \cdot,\cdot \}$ is an anticommutator and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Comment: What do you want to know about this thing?

Comment: I'm curious, how did this crop up? (Also, what's "$H$"?)

Comment: Thanks for comments. Dr NoahSchweber : This algebra arose from work on the "classical limit" of deformed q-bosons. If H is a function of X^2 + Y^2, then the algebra obeys the Jacobi Identity and thought it may be a disguised Lie algebra, or perhaps a Lie superalgebra. Prof PeterKravchuk: I wanted to know if it was a standard structure because it looks quite symmetric and interesting and I have an interested in deformed uncertainty relations. Prof @CosmasZachos : I'm afraid that I can't immediately see that H^3 = 0. Do I multiply out the commutator for H?

Comment: There are at least two ways you can interpret "algebraic structure" here: you might be asking whether this is like an algebra or a Lie algebra or what (the answer is that it is an algebra: in the presence of a commutator and an anticommutator you can recover a multiplication, at least if you're allowed to divide by $2$), or second, you might already know the answer to this question and want to know the name of this particular algebra or Lie algebra or whatever.

Comment: Thank you Dr @QiaochuYuan. I appreciate that the set of elements with these relations form an algebra and I have some knowledge of Lie algebras and QUEAs (and not so much experience of super-versions of these). I was just interested as the formal structure seemed to be very simple and exhibit nice symmetry properties. I thought perhaps it was a simple example of a codified mathematical structure of which I am ignorant.

Answer (score 3):

I'm merely replying to your comment question: Apologies, $H^3$ does *not* vanish.

It is evident from your three relations that you may take *H,X,Y* hermitian.

It is also evident that the structure of your algebra simplifies upon defining
$$
Z\equiv X+iY, \qquad Z^\dagger =X-i Y, 
$$
so that 
$$
H Z=0, \qquad Z^\dagger H=0 , \qquad [Z,Z^\dagger ]=2H ~.
$$

So, then , multiplying the last relation (commutator) by *H*s on the left and the right yields $HZ^\dagger ZH =-2H^3$, instead. It might not be too hard to find a simple matrix realization of the algebra.

Generically, as per your comment, it appears like a deformed QUE (quantized universal enveloping) algebra of an SU(2) Lie algebra. Ideally, you'd seek the singular map from the Lie algebra to it, as in this [1991 mini-review](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/paradig.pdf) of mine.

Comment: As you probably surmised, the algebra {X, Y, H} came from looking at the q-deformation of the complex plane. It looks like a "classical" counterpart of the q-boson algebra introduced by Kempf, back in the 90s. Many thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, I did try to find a quick deformer for it in [this talk](https://www.academia.edu/17679986/Quantized_planes_and_multiparameter_deformations_of_Heisenberg_and_GL_N_algebras) but without ready success.